# What would be the cardinality of $S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients satisfying $$f(x)\equiv 1\mod (x-1)$$ and $$f(x)\equiv 0\mod (x-3)$$

What would be the cardinality of $S$?

Second equation means $x=3$ is a root of $f(x)$. That means $f(3)\equiv 1\mod2 $
 and that means $0\equiv 1\mod 2$ which is a contradiction. So $S$ is empty.

Please have a look at the work. Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure of the use you give to "congruent to", but imo $\;f(x)\cong 1\mod{(x-1)}\;$ means $\;f(1)=1\;$, whereas I agree with the other one that $\;f(3)=0\;$ . Thus, for example, $\;f(x)=-\frac12(x-3)\in S\;$ ...Am I missing something? I honestly didn't understand what you did with $\;\mod 2\;$ and all that...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think OP means, for example, that $f(5) \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $f(5) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Comment: OP: No, your reasoning is not correct.  $f(3) \equiv 0 \pmod 0$ is kind of meaningless.  You haven't explained what domains these modular equations are supposed to hold over.

Comment: @BrianTung Perhaps, yet why would he use polynomials then? $\;f(x)]\cong 1\mod{(x-1)}\;$ shouild mean, imo, that $\;f(x)=q(x)(x-1)+1\;$ ...I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited

Comment: @DonAntonio: Although...I just realized that there is no value for $f(5)$ which can be equivalent to $1$ modulo $4$ and to $0$ modulo $2$.

Comment: @BrianTung Please see the edited post. I hope it clears the notation

Comment: @BrianTung And I still can't understand why you care about $\;f(5)\;$ **precisely...

Comment: @StammeringMathematician How in the world $3$ being a root of $\;f\;$ would imply $\;f(3)=1\pmod 2\;$ ?! It would imply $\;f(3)=0=0\pmod 2\;$ ...! I think you better write down **the definition** of your "congruency" .

Comment: @DonAntonio: It's just an example, but it's an example which leads me to suspect that either (a) there aren't any solutions, or (b) I've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I think you got confused writing your argument. You probably want to say that, since $3\equiv 1 \pmod 2$, then $0=f(3)\equiv f(1)=1 \pmod 2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Well, everything is useless and hopeless as long as the OP doesn't clarify completely what that $\;\cong\;$ relation means applied to polynomials...

Comment: It's rather obvious from context that the congruences of polynomials are intended to take place in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (or perhaps some larger ring of polynomials like $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but it doesn't make a difference since $x-1$ and $x-3$ are monic).

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you! That's my point from the beginning...but **no** : it is not that "obvious" as the explanation the OP gave, and still gives, in his post doesn't fit into that...

Comment: @DonAntonio This was asked in a competitive exam(CSIR NET June 2018). I copied the statement of problem as it is. I put $x=3$ in $f(x)\equiv 1\mod (x-1)$. That is how I get $f(3)\equiv 1 \mod 2$. Is it wrong. Thanks for taking time to go through the problem.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I think I finanlly got it. I think your argument is correct. You can see my proposed answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after the very last comment below the question by the OP I think the following can be what was intended: it is given $\;f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ s.t. both the following are true:

$$\begin{cases}I\;\;\;f(x)\cong1\mod{(x-1)}\iff f(x)=1+(x-1)p(x)\;,\;\;p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\\{}\\
II\;\;f(x)\cong0\mod{(x-3)}\iff f(x)=(x-3)q(x)\;,\;\;q(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\end{cases}$$

but then we get:

$$\begin{cases}I\;\implies\; f(1)=1=1\pmod 2\\{}\\
II\implies f(1)=-2q(1)=0\pmod2\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\text{ contradiction}$$

and what the OP did is thus correct: we get that in fact $\;S=\emptyset\;$ .

Comment: This was an interesting question:...and I think it was clear from the very beginning! It is just the proposed solution by the OP succeeded in confusing me...and apparently some others as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is correct, but mixing the meaning of $\equiv$ between the ring of intergers and the ring of integer polynomials is a dangerous thing to do, because it is not obvious if one equation interpreted as over one ring will hold over the other, or even what interpretation you are using at any given moment.

For a polynomial $p$ I'll use the notion $p(x)$ when I'm talking about the element of the polynomial ring and $p[y]$ when I'm talking about the result of 'applying' $p(x)$ to the integer $y$.

But at least one direction is easy: If $a(x),b(x)$ and $q(x)$ are integer plynomials, and

$$a(x) \equiv b(x) \pmod {q(x)}$$

is true, it is also true that

$$\forall x\in \mathbb Z:a[x] \equiv b[x] \pmod {q[x]}$$

That's because in the ring of integer polynomials we know there exists a polynomial $k(x)$ with

$$a(x)-b(x) = k(x)q(x).$$

Now addition and multiplication of polynomials have been designed such that they 'mimic' the functional evaluation, so we can derive from this that

$$\forall x\in \mathbb Z: a[x]-b[x] = k[x]q[x]$$

which then implies what we wanted to proof.

You applied the polynomial ring interpretation to your equation

$$f(x)\equiv 0\mod (x-3)$$

to arrive at (in my notation)

$$f[3]=0$$

and used the integer ring interpretation of

$$f(x)\equiv 1\mod (x-1)$$

for $x=3$ to get (in my notation)

$$f[3] \equiv 1 \mod 2,$$

which is a contradiction, as you noted. My above proof shows that you can go from the polynomial ring interpretation to the integer ring interpretation. But as I said in the beginning, to prevent errors, one should distinguish between working in one ring and the other, if possible.

Comment: It should perhaps also be mentioned that for the implication you mention to be correct, the statement $a(x) \equiv b(x) \pmod {q(x)}$ must take place in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ rather than a larger ring like $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ or $\mathbb{R}[x]$, so that $k(x)$ has integer coefficients.  For this particular problem it doesn't make a difference though ($k(x)$ will always have integer coefficients since it can be found by long division by $q(x)=x-1$ which involves no division of coefficients since $q(x)$ is monic).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then $f(x)$ is an integer whenever $x$ is an integer. Moreover, if $a$ and $b$ are distinct integers, then $a-b$ divides $f(a) - f(b)$.

In this case, $f$ would need to satisfy $f(1) = 1$ and $f(3) = 0$, meaning that $3-1$ would have to divide $f(3) - f(1) = -1$.

Hence there are no polynomials with those properties.

Answer (score -2):

$f(x)\equiv  1\bmod (x-1)$ is a congruent condition as polynomials, i.e. $f(x)=1+p(x)(x-1)$ for some polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. In particular, $f(3)=1+p(3)(2)$. Note that $p(3)$ (a priori) does not need to be integer, so saying $f(3)\equiv 1\bmod 2$ is not justified unless you can prove that $p(3)\in\mathbb{Z}$ (which would be true if you can prove $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$)

Comment: I agree with the first part, yet about the second one: it is given the polynomial is an *integer* one, and thus we definitely have $\;p(3)\in\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio: Well, the polynomial that is known to be integer is $f(\cdot)$, not $p(\cdot)$.  But I don't agree with a definition of modular equivalence which permits $p(\cdot)$ to hold non-integer values.  Otherwise, any value $x$ could be equivalent to $1$ modulo $2$, simply by using the appropriate multiplier on $2$.

Comment: @BrianTung What $\;p\;$ are you talking about, anyway?

Comment: @DonAntonio: He says that $f \equiv 1 \pmod u$ implies that there is some $p$ such that $f = 1 + p \cdot u$.  We normally require $p$ to be an integer, because otherwise, it's meaningless to say that $f \equiv 1 \pmod u$.  We could say that, for instance, $\pi$ is odd because $\pi = 1 + 2p$, where $p = \frac{\pi-1}{2}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I didn't see that $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and I think with that you can prove that $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry but I can't understand where you see that anywhere in the original post...

Comment: @BrianTung, it makes sense to talk about modularity seen as polynomials, when you divide two polynomials you can express $f(x)=q(x)(x-3)+r(x)$ where $deg(r)<1$, i.e. $r$ is some constant. In this case they are telling you that $r$ is in fact 1.

Comment: @JulianMejia Again, I can't see where in the Original post, either the edited one of the first one, is there **any** $\;p\;$ at all...!@

Comment: @DonAntonio What does it mean $17\equiv 2\mod 5$? It means that there is some $p=3$ such that $17=2+5p$. But in this case we are looking at polynomials, so $f(x)\equiv 1\mod(x-3)$ means $f(x)=1+(x-3)p(x)$.

Comment: @JulianMejia That I already wrote many comments ago...perhaps with different names. You though seemed to be talking of a very specific, unnamed polynomial.

Comment: @DonAntonio this comment section is from my answer, not from the post. In my answer I explained what was $p(x)$.

Comment: Use `\bmod` for the binary operator, that has equal spacing on both sides; for the parenthetical operator, use `\pmod`. Compare `a\equiv b\mod x`, `a\equiv b\bmod x` and `a\equiv b\pmod{x}`:  $a\equiv b\mod x$, $a\equiv b\bmod x$, $a\equiv b \pmod{x}$.